# UIView is not scrollable inside scrollview

Tags: ios

I have view inside scrollview. Inside UIView there are many objects. I want that view should be scrollable.

[image: Here is screenshot]

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Hey, can you get a screenshot of the storyboard and post it in a link ?

Comment: yeah.. i have just updated question

Comment: can you expand the constraint that is closed, second up from the selected constraint

Comment: Follow this answer for whatever issues you may have with scroll views. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18&feature=youtu.be) the video version.

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar have a look.

Comment: the height and width constraint for the UIScrollView child view(UIVIew) is available in the collapsed constraint, which is not visible here.

Comment: one solution is that to embed all objects inside view to vertical stack view and add 0, 0, 0, 0 constraints and centerX constraint

Comment: @K.R.SaravanaKumar i don't have width and height constraints to UIView. just leading, trailling, top, bottom

Comment: Can you compress your project os this storyboard and add a gdrive link?

Comment: Thanks everyone, but i prefer to use stack view. It suits perfectly

Comment: Okay. have a good day

Comment: check this video [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buJUK87fmmI)

Answer (score 1):

I think UIView is not suitable for this kind of situation, because there are many objects aligned vertically, so i prefer to use stack view. Now scroll is working!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand first how UIScrollView works. There should be a warning message that says like this:

> ScrollView has ambiguous scrollable content

Your scrollView won't scroll because it means that the subviews of your scrollView does not have enough constraints attached to them and to the scrollView to make the scrollView scroll. Well how does the scrollView scroll? If the content of the scrollView exceeds the frame (either width or height) of the scrollView, then the scrollView will be scrollable.

Comment: i have already add enought constrains to subview.. what should i do more?

Comment: Well, you can review the constraints again one by one. From top to bottom. And take heed of the warnings in Xcode about the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Adding height of contentview(view) inside scrollview will make the scrollview scroll with other necessary constraints

Answer (score 0):

Better You can Increase the view controller's Height and add a scroll view with it 
I hope this video helps.

- [How To Create A Scroll View In Xcode 8 (Swift 3.0)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhhW3xqhCzg)